# Kedro and Streamlit Integration - Running Kedro Pipeline with Custom DataCatalog

Tags: python, streamlit, catalog, kedro

I am working on integrating Kedro, a data pipeline framework, with Streamlit, a popular Python web app framework, to build a data processing application. The primary goal is to run a specific Kedro pipeline from within my Streamlit app, using a custom `DataCatalog` to manage and load DataFrames.

Problem Details:

1. Integration Background:

   I have successfully integrated Kedro and Streamlit, and I can run Kedro pipelines from my Streamlit app. However, I want to pass custom data loaded in Streamlit as a `DataCatalog` to the Kedro pipeline for processing.
2. Data Loading in Streamlit:

   In Streamlit, I use file uploaders to load data from various sources (e.g., CSV, Excel). I then create DataFrames from this data.
3. Running Kedro Pipeline:

   After loading and processing the data in Streamlit, I want to execute a specific Kedro pipeline, passing the custom `DataCatalog` containing the loaded DataFrames. The pipeline processes this data and stores the results.
4. Error Encountered:

   When I attempt to run the Kedro pipeline with the custom `DataCatalog`, I encounter the following error messages:

   - `TypeError: KedroSession.run() got an unexpected keyword argument 'extra_params'`
   - `AttributeError: can't set attribute 'catalog'`
   - `AttributeError: 'KedroContext' object has no attribute 'pipeline_registry'`

How can I properly run a Kedro pipeline from within a Streamlit app, passing a dynamically created DataCatalog?
Kedro Version: Latest
Streamlit Version: Latest

```py
# Code block 1: Loading data in Streamlit
if st.button('Processar Dados de Entrada'):
    # Executar a pipeline do Kedro
    with KedroSession.create(project_path=project_path) as session:
        catalog = DataCatalog({
            "reagentes_raw": MemoryDataSet(df1),
            "balanco_de_massas_raw": MemoryDataSet(df2),
            "laboratorio_raw": MemoryDataSet(df3),
            "laboratorio_raiox_raw": MemoryDataSet(df4),
            "carta_controle_pims_raw": MemoryDataSet(df5),
            "blend_raw": MemoryDataSet(df6)
        })
        session.run(data_catalog=catalog, pipeline_name="tag_web_app")
    st.success('Dados de entrada processados com sucesso!')

    # Ler o arquivo Parquet após a execução da pipeline
    merged_data = catalog.load("merged_raw_data_process")
    # Supondo que o arquivo Parquet tenha uma coluna de timestamp
    last_update = merged_data['timestamp_column'].max()
    st.header('Resultado da Atualização da base de dados')
    st.write(f"Dados de entrada processados com sucesso: a data e hora da informação mais recente é {last_update.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')}")

# Code block 2: Attempt to set DataCatalog in KedroContext
if st.button('Processar Dados de Entrada'):
    with KedroSession.create(project_path=project_path) as session:
        context = session.load_context()
        context.catalog = catalog  # This line triggers an AttributeError
        runner = SequentialRunner()
        session.run(pipeline_name="tag_web_app")
        runner.run(pipeline=context.pipeline_registry.get("tag_web_app"), catalog=catalog)  # This line triggers an AttributeError
```

Error 2:

```py
AttributeError: can't set attribute 'catalog'
```

Error 3:

```py
AttributeError: 'KedroContext' object has no attribute 'pipeline_registry'
```

Comment: Hi @Riuk2252, could you share the complete tracebacks of Error 1? It's unclear where does it come from

Comment: Also, what version of Kedro are you using?

Comment: @astrojuanlu 0.18.14 and forget the error number 1

Comment: Left an answer just explaining the errors, happy to iterate a bit more. It's also unclear to me why you are doing `session.run(pipeline_name="tag_web_app")` followed by `runner.run(...)`

Comment: @Riuk2252 Maybe oversimplifying, but couldn't you just point to a config you render instead of trying to create the config inline? In docs - https://docs.kedro.org/en/stable/development/commands_reference.html#modifying-a-kedro-run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Error 2

```
AttributeError: can't set attribute 'catalog'
```

`KedroSession.catalog` has been read-only for a while, what you are trying to do cannot be done.

### Error 3

```
AttributeError: 'KedroContext' object has no attribute 'pipeline_registry'
```

`KedroContext` never had a `pipeline_registry` property.